# Javascript get all parameters from url (windows.location)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all parameters from an url.

Example:

```
http://domain.com/page?param1=values&param2=values2?param3=value3....&paramx=valuex
```

I am using this:

```
window.location.search.substring(1).split("&")
```

It works quite ok, except that all the parameters delimiters `&` are replaced by comma `,`

Basically the parameters above are returned like this:

```
param1=values,param2=values2,param3=value3,....,paramx=valuex
```

Any idea how can can I get the parameters as they are?

Comment: No, the `&` characters are not replaced by commas. You're misinterpreting the console output.  The `.split()` function returns an **array**, not a string.

Comment: That might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascriptà

Comment: Sooo then I should use instead: `window.location.search.substring(1).split("?")` which will return an array of 2 elements and get the second element (1) ... right?

Comment: In think the second `?` should be a `&` in your example (after `param2=values2`). And `window.location.search.substring(1).split("&")` was already the good solution.

Comment: expanding on other comments, here's a fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/vowxd0y2/

Answer (score 2):

See this article on MDN.  It answers your question.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

```
var oGetVars = {};
if (window.location.search.length > 1) {
  for (var aItKey, nKeyId = 0, aCouples = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&"); nKeyId < aCouples.length; nKeyId++) {
    aItKey = aCouples[nKeyId].split("=");
    oGetVars[decodeURIComponent(aItKey[0])] = aItKey.length > 1 ? decodeURIComponent(aItKey[1]) : "";
  }
}
// alert(oGetVars.yourVar);
```

Comment: Any particular reason this was down voted when it links to an article from an authoritative source that contains the EXACT code you are looking for?

Comment: Example 7, 8, 9, etc

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the explantation

Comment: By the way I didn't down vote you, your answer appeared in the SO low quality post queue, one of the options was the stock comment I left, you will find that most down voters don't leave a comment

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have edited my original answer and I will remember this in the future.